# If $f(x)=mx+b$ and $g(x)=nx+c$, and the graphs are perpendicular, how do we prove that $mn=-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $f(x)=mx+b$ and $g(x)=nx+c$.
>
> Prove that the graphs of $f$ and $g$ are perpendicular if $mn=-1$.

If I set $b=c=0$, there is a proof using geometry.

[image]

If the two lines are perpendicular then the triangle above satisfies

$$(1+n^2)+(1+m^2)=(m-n)^2=m^2+n^2-2mn$$
$$\implies mn=-1$$

**How do we prove the more general result?**

The following is an attempt at the same strategy used above.

[image]

EDIT: I am looking for a proof that doesn't involve vector dot product.

This problem is from one of the early chapter's of Spivak's Calculus (chapter 4, Graphs). Dot product wasn't introduced at that point. The solution manual gave the geometric proof above and then said "the general case follows from this special case, since perpendicularity depends only on the slope". I am looking perhaps for a proof of this statement.

Comment: "*If I set $b=c=0$, there is a proof using geometry*" $\;$ The graphs of $f(x)$ and $f(x-a)$ are parallel lines for any constant $a$, so you can use your proof for $f(x - b/m)$ and $g(x-c/n)$. The attempt to prove the general case directly will also work after you replace $x_0(m-n)=c-b$ in the last equality.

Answer (score 2):

**Proof using dot product :**

The points $A(0,b)$ and $B(1,m+b)$ belong to the graph of $f$, and the points $C(0,c)$ and $D(1,n+c)$ belong to the graph of $g$.

The graphs are perpendicular iff $\vec{AB}.\vec{CD}=0$, which is equivalent to $1+mn=0$, and you are done.

**Alternate proof that don't use dot product :**

The angle between the graph of $f$ and the $x-$axis is given by $\arctan(m)$, and the angle between the graph of $g$ and the $x-$axis is given by $\arctan(n)$. Without loss of generality, we can suppose that $\arctan(m) \geq \arctan(n)$ and that $m \neq 0$.

You deduce that the graphs are perpendicular iff $\arctan(m)-\arctan(n) = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, and because of the famous relation $\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, you deduce that $\dfrac{1}{m} = -n$ and you are done.

Comment: Your proof is correct, but I should have written in my question that I am looking for a proof that doesn't use vector dot product.

Comment: @evianpring I edited.